# AOP advice on methods other than execute method of spring batch tasklet not being applied

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-aop

This issue has started after migrating from spring 4.1.2 to 5.0.5, spring batch to 3.0.9 to 4.0.1 and hibernate 4.2.0 to 5.2.16
I have a spring batch tasklet of the format -

```
public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
                    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1) {
                        a();
                    }
                    public void a(){
                    //a few hibernate calls here
                    }
        }
```

Now I want my hibernate transaction boundary to be the method a() [being called from execute] and not the execute() method.
But when I try applying point-cuts to achieve the same I get a message *"no transaction in progress"*. I have provided the sample xml below.

In the aop pointcut -instead of the method name 'a'[i.e `public * myPackage.MyTasklet.a(..)`], if I use `*` (i.e `public * myPackage.MyTasklet.*(..)`] or 'execute'[i.e `public * myPackage.MyTasklet.execute(..)`] the code works fine. Due to some technical reasons it is important to have the boundary at 'a' due to which I cannot have 'execute' or any other method as the boundary.

---

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="Op1"
            expression="execution(public * myPackage.MyTasklet.a(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="Op1" />
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked hundreds of times here. Your method `a()` is called internally, but internal method calls are never intercepted by Spring AOP because in that case you actually call `this.a()`. This does not go through the wrapping dynamic proxy used by Spring AOP. If `a()` was called from outside, e.e. by another component, it would work. This behaviour is [comprehensively documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) in the Spring AOP manual.

If you want to intercept internal method calls you have to use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. How to configure Spring for [AspectJ and LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) is also documented in the Spring manual.

P.S.: This is completely unrelated to your version upgrades. In older Spring and Spring Batch versions it would be the same. You mixed **refactoring** (version upgrade) with **functional changes**, which you should never do. Too many moving targets for debugging. Refactoring means to change the code (or the configuration, in this case) without changing its functionality.